# Retrieve stored procedure information from Snowflake using perl DBI

Tags: perl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a bunch of stored procedures in Snowflake and I can run a get_ddl procedure to pull the information from a SF worksheet.  However in using perl's DBI I can run the select for the get_ddl, however its not showing the local declarations.  I use the fetchrow to pull the data.

```
     while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
       print "row is @row\n";
     }
```

This is return from Snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_LOAD_AMT"("MASTER_ID" FLOAT, "TARGETING_PROFILES" VARCHAR(16777216), "DELIMITER" VARCHAR(1), "DEBUG" BOOLEAN)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
// Local function declarations --------------------------------------------------------
function createLogger(masterId, processType, functionName, debug) {
    var loggingContext, log;

    function LoggingContext(masterId, processType, functionName, debug) {
        var stmt, resultSet;

        if(Number.isInteger(masterId)) {
            stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
                sqlText: `SELECT CNTXT:CNTRL_STEP:MASTER_ID AS MASTER_ID, 
                            CNTXT:CNTRL_STEP:BATCH_ID AS BATCH_ID
                        FROM (SELECT METAPROC.GET_RUNTIME_CONTEXT(?) AS CNTXT);`,
                binds: [masterId]
            });
```

But the only return from the perl script DBI fetchrow is the top portion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_LOAD_AMT"("MASTER_ID" FLOAT, "TARGETING_PROFILES" VARCHAR(16777216), "DELIMITER" VARCHAR(1), "DEBUG" BOOLEAN)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
```

Does anyone know how I can pull the rest of the stored procedures function?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to use the DBA role within snowflake.  All good.